# How to parse protobuf message in kotlinx serialization

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, kotlinx.serialization

I have a protobuf message `Request` and `Response`. What is the correct representation of this for Kotlin `data class` for `kolinx.serialization`. Protobuf serialization is still experimental  [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/formats.md). Can I use the `kolinx.serialization` to serialize and deserialize these messages?

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "cz.cvut.fel.esw.server.proto";

message Request {
  message GetCount {};
  message PostWords {
    bytes data = 1;
  }
  oneof msg {
    GetCount getCount = 1;
    PostWords postWords = 2;
  }
}

message Response {
  enum Status { OK = 0; ERROR = 1;};

  Status status = 1; // Always present
  int32 counter = 2;
  string errMsg = 3;
}
```